# Plot a point on a line closest to a point

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have the equation for the closest distance from a point (p3) to a line (through p1 and p2) defined from:

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#:~:text=In%20Euclidean%20geometry%2C%20the%20distance,nearest%20point%20on%20the%20line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#:%7E:text=In%20Euclidean%20geometry%2C%20the%20distance,nearest%20point%20on%20the%20line).

This code snippet plots the 3 points, but how do I plot the point on that line with the calculated distance, d?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1=1; y1=5
x2=6; y2=7
x3=0; y3=0

p1 = x1,y1
p2 = x2,y2
p3 = x3,y3

d = abs((x2-x1)*(y1-y3) - (x1-x3)*(y2-y1)) / np.sqrt(np.square(x2-x1) + np.square(y2-y1))

%matplotlib inline
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
plt.scatter(x1,y1,color="red",marker=".",label="p1")
plt.scatter(x2,y2,color="blue",marker=".",label="p2")
plt.scatter(x3,y3,color="black",marker=".",label="p3")
plt.legend()
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

This is how I solved the problem before some really helpful answers came in (below).

I used these equations on Wikipedia

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1=1; y1=5
x2=6; y2=7
x0=0; y0=0

p1 = x1,y1
p2 = x2,y2
p3 = x0,y0

A = y2-y1
B = x2-x1
C = (x1*y2)-(x2*y1)

x4 = ( B*(B*x0-A*y0) - A*C ) / (A*A + B*B)
y4 = ( A*(A*y0-B*x0) - B*C ) / (A*A + B*B)

P4 = x4;y4

%matplotlib notebook
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
plt.scatter(x1,y1,color="red",marker=".",label="p1")
plt.scatter(x2,y2,color="blue",marker=".",label="p2")
plt.scatter(x0,y0,color="black",marker=".",label="p3")
plt.scatter(x4,y4,color="green",marker=".",label="p4")
plt.legend()
```

But JohanC pointed out that my sign was wrong for equation A=y2-y1. It needs to be A=y1-y2. This correctly plotted the point on a line.

Comment: this is more a math question, and you should be able to calculate the exact coordinates of d then plot it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the line through 2 points in the form of `ax + by + c = 0`. In order to find `a`, `b` and `c`, you could employ [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html), Python's symbolic math package. We need both `x1,y1` and `x2,y2` to belong to `ax + by + c = 0`

```py
from sympy import Eq, symbols, solve

x1, y1, x2, y2, a, b, c = symbols('x1 y1 x2 y2 a b c ')
solve([Eq(a * x1 + b * y1 + c, 0), Eq(a * x2 + b * y2 + c, 0)], (a, b, c))
```

This gives:

`{a: c*(y1 - y2)/(x1*y2 - x2*y1), b: c*(-x1 + x2)/(x1*y2 - x2*y1)}`

So, setting `c = x1*y2 - x2*y1`, `a = y1 - y2` and `b = x2 - x1` would be a formulation without divisions.

Then, a perpendicular will have an equation `bx - ay + c3 = 0` for some `c3` such that both `x3,y3` and `x4,y4` belong to that line.

```py
x3, y3, x4, y4, a, b, c, c3 = symbols('x3 y3 x4 y4 a b c c3')
solve([Eq(a * x4 + b * y4 + c, 0), Eq(b * x3 - a * y3 + c3, 0), Eq(b * x4 - a * y4 + c3, 0)], (x4, y4, c3))
```

This gives as solution for `x4` and `y4`:

```
{x4: (-a*b*y3 - a*c + b**2*x3)/(a**2 + b**2),
 y4: (a**2*y3 - a*b*x3 - b*c)/(a**2 + b**2), c3: a*y3 - b*x3}
```

The latest version of matplotlib (3.4.1) has a function [`plt.axline()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axline.html) to draw an unlimited line:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = 1; y1 = 5
x2 = 6; y2 = 7
x3 = 0; y3 = 0

p1 = x1, y1
p2 = x2, y2
p3 = x3, y3

a = y1 - y2
b = x2 - x1
c = (x1 * y2) - (x2 * y1)

x4 = (b * (b * x3 - a * y3) - a * c) / (a * a + b * b)
y4 = (a * (a * y3 - b * x3) - b * c) / (a * a + b * b)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
plt.scatter(x1, y1, color="red", marker=".", s=200, label="p1")
plt.scatter(x2, y2, color="blue", marker=".", s=200, label="p2")
plt.scatter(x3, y3, color="black", marker=".", s=200, label="p3")
plt.scatter(x4, y4, color="green", marker=".", s=200, label="p4")
plt.axline((x1, y1), (x2, y2), linestyle='--', color='black', zorder=0)
plt.plot((x3, x4), (y3, y4), linestyle=':', color='black', zorder=0)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.legend()
```

[image: projecting a point on a line]

Comment: I didnt know sympy even existed. This is very helpful! Thanks so much for your time answering the questions!